# Click Function for Dynamic Content from JSON Array

Tags: json, function, dom, jquery

I have a PHP file that serves up a JSON array populated from a MySQL database and is loaded into the DOM. This data is loaded via jQuery getJSON() method into the #navContent divide of the HTML document. This functions as planed.

At the very-bottom of the HTML doc, I have a click function that targets the #navItem div that was dynamically loaded into the DOM but this does not fire. I am assuming the `<li ID = 'navItem'...` isnt kept when the data is dynamically populated..??

What do I have wrong? For now, I just want all the divides that were dynamically created into the #navContent div to click thru to a URL.

```
<html>
. . .
<head>
. . .
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ajaxLoader = '';
    var container = "navItem";
    var appendE = "navContent";
    var dns = 'http://192.168.1.34';
    var navContent = '/andaero/php/regulatory_list.php';
    var bodyContent = '/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content';

    <!-- ================ When Ready Do This ============================ -->
    <!-- **************************************************************** --> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
          loadNav(dns + navContent, container, appendE);//<- This gets loaded into the navContent<div
          loadPage(dns + bodyContent, "bodyContent");

     });
   . . .
</script>
<body>
    . . .
<div id="navScrollContainer" class="navContentPosition">
                <div id="navContent" >
                    <li id="navItem" style="display: none;">
                        <h1 class="navH1"></h1>
                        <h2 class="navH2"></h2>
                        <p class="navP"></p>
                        <hr class="navHR" />
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
. . .
</body>

<!-- ================ Functions ===================================== -->
<!-- **************************************************************** -->

<script type="text/javascript">

    /* --------------- Handle Pg Loading ----------------- */
    function loadPage(url, pageName) {
        $("#" + pageName).load(url, function(response){
    //          transition("#" + pageName, "fade", false);
        });
    };

    function loadNav(url, container, appendE) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){

            $.each(data.items, function(){

                var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();

                // Now fill in the fields with the data
                newItem.find("h1").text(this.label);
                newItem.find("h2").text(this.title);
                newItem.find("p").text(this.description);

                // And add the new list item to the page
                newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE)
            });

            $('#navHeaderTitle').text(data.key);
            //transition("#" + pageName, "show");
        });

        $('#navItem').click(function(e){ //<-- THIS IS BROKE!! HELP!!
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#bodyContent').load('www.google.com');
        });
    };
</scrip>
</html>
```

**============ EDIT ================**

I tried everything that was sugested with no prevail. I ended up using the code Shyju answered with but one modification to get it to work: As per the docs,

> .on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) ), I changed [,data] from the tag ID to just the tag type. ie: *a*. This function now since I wrapped the whole
>
> with the  tag.  See bellow:

Changed HTML to:

```
<div id="navScrollContainer" class="navContentPosition">
    <div id="navContent" >
        <li id="navItem" style="display: none;">
            <a> //<-- ADDED THIS TAG WRAPPER!!
            <h1 class="navH1"></h1>
            <h2 class="navH2"></h2>
            <p class="navP"></p>
            <hr class="navHR" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div
```

Changed the Function to (Note that .on() allows a click event on any TAG element--even new ones--since the event is handled by the ever-present previous element after it bubbles to there.:

```
$('#navContent').on('click', 'a', function(e){//<--CHANGED DATA TO 'a'
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#bodyContent').load('http://www.google.com');   
});
```

Comment: Sorry this has been a chain of questions related to this dynamic content.  Thnx for all your help everyone.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for dynamic content, you should use jquery `on`.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

So your code should look like this

```
$("#navScrollContainer").on("click","#navItem").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#bodyContent').load('www.google.com');
});
```

But i guess **you should not use the id selector for click event, because ids will (And should) be unique for an element**. So when you load new content, the id will be different i believe. Probably you can use class name which is common for all those elements to be clicked.

on method is availabe from jQuery 1.7 version only. If you are using a previous version, you should use `live` as Niyaz mentioned.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thnx! this didnt work but got me on the correct track. Plz see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('#navItem').click(function(){});
```

try using:

```
$('#navItem').live('click', function(){}); // jQuery older than 1.7
```

or

```
$('#navItem').on('click', function(){}); // jQuery 1.7 or newer
```

Comment: He didn't use it incorrectly, but he used it incorrectly as a replacement for `live()`. What's there is the replacement for `click()`.

Comment: @Dylan Cross Thnx! this didnt work but got me on the correct track. Plz see my edit above.

Comment: @GregPettit Yes, that's what I meant, I was just in a hurry to comment and left that out.

Comment: @DylanCross Yup, I meant that for Matthew; I was surprised he didn't catch your meaning. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear so that all your nav elements are created with the same ID. This

```
$('#navItem').click(function(e){ //<-- THIS IS BROKE!! HELP!!
```

will apply to only one of them I suppose. Try adding some sort of counter to the ID when you are cloning:

```
var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
newItem.attr("id","something_unique_in_here");
```